# ERROR getting error Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-refresh/runtime'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

Hola estoy migrando los componentes de mi app de react a typescript, y tuve este problema de dependencias de react-refresh, alguno tuvo este problema?

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Dashboard.js 1:40-137
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/eddy/Descargas/proyectos/Turboweb/turboweb/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/pages/LoginPage.js 1:40-137
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/eddy/Descargas/proyectos/Turboweb/turboweb/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/pages/Register.js 1:40-137
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/eddy/Descargas/proyectos/Turboweb/turboweb/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Comment: ¿Leíste lo que dice el mensaje de error? De hecho te está diciendo qué tenés que hacer.